# How to set a variable for session in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm just getting started with Rails and I'm a little confused about how I would set a variable for a session.

In my app, I want a user to be able to choose either English or French and, when they click on article, it displays in the selected language.

If they select English, it is saved as 'Preferred_lang'. However, they can change it at any time.

Right now, I have this condition at the beginning of the Articles show page:

```
- if current_user.preferred_lang = 'English'
  = render 'english'
- else
  = render 'french'
```

It doesn't seem very efficient to me. Is there a way to set 'current_language' at the beginning of the session and then to update it if the user changes it?

Comment: Not efficient? What do you mean, the branching? Why not efficient?

Comment: It seemed like it to me. Maybe I'm wrong, but learning how to do something like this wouldn't be harmful.

Answer (score 4):

Its just a key, value pair( Hash ). So you can set it like this:

```
session[:preferred_lang] = @current_user.preferred_lang
```

you can then use it:

```
if session[:preferred_lang]
  # I found a previously set preferred_lang
else
  # No previously set prefferd_lang
end
```

Then you can update it at any point and delete if you wish.